# Why do stylesheets not work when subclassing QWidget and using Q_OBJECT?

Tags: qt

Case 1: Create subclass of QWidget with Q_OBJECT and set stylesheet -- no effect.

Case 2: Create subclass of QWidget without Q_OBJECT and set stylesheet -- works as expected

Case 3: Create subclass of QLabel with Q_OBJECT and set stylesheet -- works as expected

How to understand this behavior? Is it possible to make stylesheets work in the case 1?

Comment: post some code pls, because from what you told us, there is only one way to understood this behaviour - you have something wrong in your code. Case 1 works just fine without any 'special technique'

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you want custom QWidget subclasses to support stylesheets, you need to provide the following code:
Qt Code:

```
void myclass::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *pe)
{                                                                                                                                        
  QStyleOption o;                                                                                                                                                                  
  o.initFrom(this);                                                                                                                                                                
  QPainter p(this);                                                                                                                                                                
  style()->drawPrimitive(
    QStyle::PE_Widget, &o, &p, this);                                                                                                                         
};
```

Courtesy of wysota, as well as Qt help.

When you don't provide Q_OBJECT, your class has no Meta data, and hence is considered as a QWidget.

Comment: According to the Qt help files, "Every widget displaying custom content must implement the paintEvent". I can only guess that by default Qt's style mechanism that draws the control (QStyle::drawControl) performs some default painting for QWidgets (as identified by meta data as result of Q_OBJECT in QWidget). As soon as you provide Q_OBJECT for your own widget derivative, the default behaviour does not hold anymore, and Qt's drawControl begins to rely on code within paintEvent to draw the control. I must admit the help files does not specify why, but only that it is required.

Comment: Direct subclasses of `QWidget` still need that `paintEvent()` override even if you provide `Q_OBJECT`.

Comment: This is also mentioned in this [wiki](https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_Change_the_Background_Color_of_QWidget#Using_Style_Sheet).

Answer (score 8):

I don't know *why* they don't work, but I translated to python the code in Werner Erasmus's answer. The following "works for me"™

```
def paintEvent(self, pe):

    o = QStyleOption()
    o.initFrom(self)
    p = QPainter(self)
    self.style().drawPrimitive(QStyle.PE_Widget, o, p, self)
```

Comment: Not working for me anymore in PyQt6 :( And you need to change the call to the PE_Widget enumeration `QStyle.PrimitiveElement.PE_Widget`

Comment: still works for me in PySide2 (v5.15.2.1), but why is this necessary in the first place, seems like a bug that just never got addressed