# A widget inside another widget does not appear

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qobject

I am writing Qt/C++ project and I created my `mainwindow.ui` in Qt Designer. I placed in `mainwindow.ui` an empty widget, which later I want to extend by putting there my widget written in code. This is my code:

Class which extends QWidget:

```
#pragma once
#include <QtGui>
#include <QWidget>

using namespace QtDataVisualization;

class GraphDataCreator : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    GraphDataCreator(QWidget* parent = 0);
    ~GraphDataCreator();
};
```

cpp of this class:

```
#include "GraphDataCreator.h"

GraphDataCreator::GraphDataCreator(QWidget* parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    this->setStyleSheet("background-color:green;");   
}
```

MainWindow class:

```
#pragma once

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "ui_MainWindow.h"
#include "GraphDataCreator.h"

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QMainWindow*parent = Q_NULLPTR);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow ui;
};
```

Source file of MainWindow class:

```
#include "MainWindow.h"
#include <string>
#include <QtGui>
#include "GraphDataCreator.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QMainWindow*parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);

    QGridLayout* layout = new QGridLayout(ui.Chart3DWidget);
    GraphDataCreator* chart3D = new GraphDataCreator(ui.Chart3DWidget);
    layout->addWidget(chart3D);


    QWidget* test_widget = new QWidget;
    test_widget->setStyleSheet("background-color: red;");
    layout->addWidget(test_widget);

    ui.Chart3DWidget->setLayout(layout);
}
```

I wanted to the whole widget be green in the UI, but it didn't appear, so I put there a `test_widget` with a red background and the result is that it is half nothing/half red. So the green widget exists there, but it is not visible.

Why is the green part not visible? And how to solve it?

Of course, names of classes are weird because I tried to do something else, and this explanation simplifies that problem.

Comment: Stylesheet you have set for your widget is "background:green;". I believe you meant to write "background-color:green;"

Comment: Yes i meant it. Anyway, stylesheet should work with both "background:green;" and "background-color:green;". But of course I tried it in code on my computer and the effects are same half nothing/half red. So unfortunetly it is not a problem with that issue

Comment: https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_Change_the_Background_Color_of_QWidget#Using_Style_Sheet
& https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18344135/why-do-stylesheets-not-work-when-subclassing-qwidget-and-using-q-object/18344643

Comment: @sajas is right, no way with QWidget.
Subclass your widget from `QFrame` and you'll get the stylesheets

Comment: @sajas thx for help! I wrote my results editting the post. Check it out if you are interested

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do stylesheets not work when subclassing QWidget and using Q\_OBJECT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18344135/why-do-stylesheets-not-work-when-subclassing-qwidget-and-using-q-object)