# QT dynamic object name for stylesheet

Tags: c++, qt, dynamic, stylesheet, objectname

I have a Card widget class, Card.h and Card.cpp my code is;
mainWindow.cpp

```
for(int i=0;i<12;i++){
   // sembolList[i] is pixmap , i is cardNumber, wCardArea is parent widget
   Card *card = new Card(sembolList[i],i,ui->wCardArea);
}
```

and I wanna reach object from inside itself
Card.cpp 
in constractor

```
this->setObjectName("card" + QString::number(cardNumber));
qDebug() << "objectName:" << this->objectName(); // this is show true object name for example card1
```

and inside of mouseclick event

```
this->setStyleSheet("#" + this->objectName() + " {border:5px solid red;border-radius: 10px;padding:5px}");
```

but this is not working. if remove ("#" + objectName) , all included widget have border. I want only first widget having border, only card have border , not its inside widget.

Answer (score 1):

According to [The Style Sheet Syntax](https://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html) arcticle, you need to specify a class name before "#".

Try

```
setStyleSheet("Card#" + objectName() + " {border:5px solid red;border-radius: 10px;padding:5px}");
```

or

```
setStyleSheet("QWidget#" + objectName() + " {border:5px solid red;border-radius: 10px;padding:5px}");
```

If still not working, read [Why do stylesheets not work when subclassing QWidget and using Q_OBJECT?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18344643/4149835)